# Manipulating React Component that Coming into Another Component as Input

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 different files which are **LogIn.js** and **CustomInput.js**
And I'm trying to change and "`type`" attribute of `<Form.Control>` component, which is coming to `<CustomInput>` component as input.

The main purpose and expected result is, get show/hide password field eye icon as an addon and to achieve it, all have to do is write `<CustomInput passwordEye />`

You will understand when you see the files.

Here is the `LogIn.js`:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import { CustomInput } from '../CustomInput'
import { Icon } from '../Icon'



const [inputType, setInputType] = useState("password")
const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)
const togglePasswordEye = () => {
    setInputType(inputType === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text')
    setShowPassword(showPassword === true ? false : true)
  }



/* START - This eye icon is working. I'm just putting this to show you a working example */
<Form.Control
              className={`form-control form-control-lg ${errors.password ? 'input-error' : ''}`}
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              type={inputType}
              name="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              tabIndex={2}
              {...register("password", {
                required: "Password is required",
                minLength: {
                  value: 6,
                  message: "Password should be more than 6 characters"
                }
              })}
            />
<span className={`password-eye cursor-pointer`} onClick={togglePasswordEye}>
                <Icon name={showPassword ? 'eye' : 'eye-slash'} />
              </span>
/* END - This eye icon is working. I'm just putting this to show you a working example */



/* START - This eye icon is NOT working but it is what I want to work */
<CustomInput passwordEye rightAddon={{icon: "eye"}} formControl={
            <Form.Control
              className={`form-control form-control-lg ${errors.password ? 'input-error' : ''}`}
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              tabIndex={2}
              {...register("password", {
                required: "Password is required",
                minLength: {
                  value: 6,
                  message: "Password should be more than 6 characters"
                }
              })}
            />
          } />
/* END- This eye icon is NOT working but it is what I want to work */
```

And here is the `CustomInput.js`:

```
import { Icon } from '../Icon'
import { useState } from 'react'



export const CustomInput = ({ formControl, rightAddon, passwordEye }) => {

  const [inputType, setInputType] = useState("password")
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)
  const togglePasswordEye = () => {
    setInputType(inputType === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text')
    setShowPassword(showPassword === true ? false : true)
  }


  if (passwordEye) {
    rightAddon.icon = showPassword ? 'eye' : 'eye-slash'
    formControl.type = inputType  // This line commented out normally because it gives error. So I know this is not the correct syntax to change "type" of <Form.Control> component inside "formControl" input, but what it?
    rightAddon.onClick = togglePasswordEye
    rightAddon.clickable = true
  }



return (

<div>
   {formControl}
   {rightAddon ?
          <span className={`password-eye ${passwordEye || rightAddon.clickable ? `cursor-pointer` : ''}`} onClick={rightAddon.onClick}>
            <Icon name={rightAddon.icon} />
          </span> : ''}
</div>

)


}
```

Eye icon graphically working both of the input on `LogIn.js`. But as functionality (switching type "text" to "password" and "password" to "text") only the first one which is not use `<CustomInput>` component.

Note that, I tried to send like that on `LogIn.js` (writing `inputType` instead of **"password"** as `type`):

```
...
<CustomInput passwordEye rightAddon={{icon: "eye"}} formControl={
            <Form.Control
              className={`form-control form-control-lg ${errors.password ? 'input-error' : ''}`}
              placeholder="Enter your password"
              type={inputType}
              name="password"
              autoComplete="current-password"
              tabIndex={2}
              {...register("password", {
                required: "Password is required",
                minLength: {
                  value: 6,
                  message: "Password should be more than 6 characters"
                }
              })}
            />
          } />
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I see in the `CustomInput` case is that you're mutating props to a React component, which is one of the cardinal rules of React, as documented here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only

I haven't tried it, but I'm fairly sure that if you rewrote your `CustomInput` by simply avoid that, it would work fine. (The fact that you're passing in a component is fine and you seem to be doing it correctly)

Comment: Ok I understand how I shouldn't, thank you for the documentation link. But still I don't know how to handle. If it is read-only, so I can read all attributes of <Form.Control> component and create a new <Form.Control> component but with different "type" attribute. I tried this but it gives error: `const formControlOverwrite = ()=>{ return ( <Form.Control {Object.entries(formControl.props).map(([key,value])=>{ key=key === "type" ? inputType : value.toString() })} /> )}`

Comment: What is the error?? @tatoline